# computer data set of Mozart piano sonatas

Tags: music

I think after 200 years the scores to the Mozart piano Sonatas are in the public domain.  I can look at the scores and download them from [IMSLP](http://imslp.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No.17_in_B-flat_major,_K.570_(Mozart,_Wolfgang_Amadeus))

[image: part of the score of Mozart's piano sonata No. 17, K. 570]

However, these are not suitable for consumption by a computer. I don't even know what the standard format is.  Could it be [MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI)? I am concerned that Midi will miss things like slurs, dynamics and other articulations (which are often put at very precise places).  Nonetheless I found [Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus [bap. Mozart, Joannes Chrysost[omus] Wolfgangus Theophilus]](http://www.kunstderfuge.com/mozart.htm) on kunstderfuge.com.

It could be quite an effort (and also error-prone) to compile these myself.  MIDI files also cannot capture the timbre of the musical instrument or a musicians artistic judgement.

Yet, are there any efforts to computerize classical music in a standard way?

Comment: What are your requirements regarding *computerized*? You mention things that (you think) won't work, what what will work? What would make a satisfactory answer?

Comment: I don't know many groups that analyze music because of the inherent difficulties involved. Our ears can distinguish between sound, for computer still next to impossible.  MIDI was a good standard in it's day, but mp3 is better if you just want to listen.

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find are some [Lilypond](http://lilypond.org/) [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LilyPond)] files  - written in a variant of [Scheme](http://lilypond.org/text-input.html) [[2](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_start)] - hosted on Mutopia.  There are only 2 of the 17 pieces you are looking for.

- [Mutopia: search for Mozart+Sonata](http://www.mutopiaproject.org/cgibin/make-table.cgi?searchingfor=mozart+sonata)

and the engraving left something to be desired.  However I did find this [index](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-es/2012-03/msg00004.html) of the 17 Mozart sonatas which looked very nice. he typesetting can look very professional when all of its features are used correctly:

[image]

and unlike with Finale or Sibelius, Lilypond is [open-source](https://github.com/lilypond/lilypond) so you retain your rights... There is also index of the [Chopin Etudes Op. 10](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/lilypond-es/2012-03/msg00005.html) which is not asked for.  Typesetting the full sonatas could be a lot of work.